# React Router & Global Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building an e-commerce website with React (my first ever React project) and I'm using React router to manage my pages.

I've got the following component tree structure:

```
<Router>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Router>
      <withRouter(Base)>
        <Route>
          <Base>
            <BaseProvider>
              <Context.Provider>
                <Header>
                  <PageContent>
```

The standard React Router structure basically, and withRouter I've got the following:

**Base.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

import { Header } from './Header';
import { Footer } from './Footer';
import Provider from '../../BaseProvider';

class Base extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider>
        <Header/>
        <div className="container">{this.props.children}</div>
        <Footer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**BaseProvider.js**

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

const Context = createContext();
const { Provider, Consumer } = Context;

class BaseProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    cart: [],
    basketTotal: 0,
    priceTotal: 0,
  };

  addProductToCart = product => {
    const cart = { ...this.state.cart };
    cart[product.id] = product;
    this.setState({ cart, basketTotal: Object.keys(cart).length });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider
        value={{ state: this.state, addProductToCart: this.addProductToCart }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export { Consumer };
export default BaseProvider;
```

This gives me a template essentially, so I just the children pages without having to include Header and Footer each time.

If I want to use my global context I'm having to import it each time, and it seems like I've done something wrong as surely I should be able to use this on any page since it's exported in BaseProvider?

If I was to visit the **About page**, I'd get the same component structure, but no access to the consumer without using:

```
import { Consumer } from '../../BaseProvider';
```

Why do I have to do this for each file even though it's exported and at the top level of my BaseProvider? It just seems such a bad pattern that I'd have to import it into about 20 files...

Without importing it, I just get:

```
Line 67:  'Consumer' is not defined  no-undef
```

I tried just adding the contextType to base but I get: Warning: withRouter(Base): Function components do not support contextType.

```
Base.contextType = Consumer;
```

I feel like I've just implemented this wrong as surely this pattern should work a lot better.

Comment: You're doing it correctly. The provider should exist at the highest level necessary to provide context to components that require it. You add the consumer where you want to access data from the provider. Any time you want to use something you're not declaring in a file, you need to import it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @Toby. Isn't the Consumer 'consumed' on every page considering it's been exported? What if I needed a global state across every file, e.g. I have products that have been added to cart & I need to change the button value based on if it's in the cart or not--global context would be ideal here. Is there no way at all to let every child in 'Base.js' consume context without having to include it? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, exporting the consumer only makes it available for importing to other files. There are other systems for managing global state, such as Redux, but that too requires importing external code. Technically in the browser you can still access the global window environment, but that's definitely not best practice. You could create a HOC - a component that wraps other components with additional functionality, and add your consumer there. You still need to import to use, but it's less code than the consumer. [More here](https://itnext.io/combining-hocs-with-the-new-reacts-context-api-9d3617dccf0b)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for @Toby, thank you!

Comment: I added this as an answer, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a Higher Order Component - a component that wraps other components with additional state or functionality.

```
const CartConsumer = Component => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <MyContext.Consumer>
          <Component />
        </MyContext.Consumer>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Then in any component where you'd like to use it, simply wrap in the export statement:

```
export default CartConsumer(ComponentWithContext)
```

This does not avoid importing completely, but it's far more minimal than using the consumer directly.